# problems adding smile statistics library to netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, import, smile

Hiho,

I'm having some problems adding the library found here to netbeans: https://github.com/haifengl/smile/releases

As you can see there's no jar available and the folder structure seems a bit off. I've tried adding the whole thing, or eg `data\src\main\java` and such seperately but it doesn't seem to find the classes... I'm not sure what I'm doing (wrong). Is anyone able to help me out here? It's so frustrating to get stuck on something like this...

Edit: For example when adding the smile project folderwise, if I create a new Dataset() in my code it will not complain about that, but the smile.data.Dataset class doesn't find eg the smile.data.Datum class (ie in the same package). So I'm not sure what I'm not sure where to begin...

Thanks